# Passive deletes in SQLAlchemy with a many-to-many relationship don't prevent DELETE from being issued for related object

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am trying to get SQLAlchemy to let my database's foreign keys "on delete cascade" do the cleanup on the association table between two objects.  I have setup the `cascade` and `passive_delete` options on the relationship as seems appropriate from the docs.  However, when a related object is loaded into the collection of a primary object and the primary object is deleted from the session, then SQLAlchemy issues a delete statement on the secondary table for the record relating the primary and secondary objects.

For example:

```python
import logging

import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative as sadec
import sqlalchemy.orm as saorm

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///')
engine.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON')

logging.basicConfig()
_logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine')

meta = sa.MetaData(bind=engine)
Base = sadec.declarative_base(metadata=meta)

sess = saorm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = sess()

blog_tags_table = sa.Table(
    'blog_tag_map',
    meta,
    sa.Column('blog_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('blogs.id', ondelete='cascade')),
    sa.Column('tag_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('tags.id', ondelete='cascade')),
    sa.UniqueConstraint('blog_id', 'tag_id', name='uc_blog_tag_map')
)


class Blog(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'blogs'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)

    tags = saorm.relationship('Tag', secondary=blog_tags_table, passive_deletes=True,
                              cascade='save-update, merge, refresh-expire, expunge')


class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)

meta.create_all(bind=engine)

blog = Blog(title='foo')
blog.tags.append(Tag(label='bar'))
session.add(blog)
session.commit()

# sanity check
assert session.query(Blog.id).count() == 1
assert session.query(Tag.id).count() == 1
assert session.query(blog_tags_table).count() == 1


_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
session.commit()

# make sure the tag is loaded into the collection
assert blog.tags[0]

session.delete(blog)
session.commit()


_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

# confirm check
assert session.query(Blog.id).count() == 0
assert session.query(Tag.id).count() == 1
assert session.query(blog_tags_table).count() == 0
```

The above code will produce DELETE statements as follows:

> DELETE FROM blog_tag_map WHERE
>   blog_tag_map.blog_id = ? AND blog_tag_map.tag_id = ?
>
> DELETE FROM blogs WHERE blogs.id = ?

Is there a way to setup the relationship so that no DELETE statement for blog_tag_map is issued?  I've also tried setting `passive_deletes='all'` with the same results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, the “related object” is *not* being deleted.  That would be “tags”.  The `blog_tags_table` is not an object, it is a many-to-many table.  Right now the `passive_deletes='all'` option is not supported for many-to-many, that is, a relationship that includes "secondary".   This would be an acceptable feature add but would require development and testing efforts.

Applying `viewonly=True` to the `relationship()` would prevent any changes from affecting the many-to-many table.    If the `blog_tags_table` is otherwise special, then you'd want to use the association object pattern to have finer grained control.

Comment: The real problem in my situation is that somehow a DELETE on the secondary table results in a StaleDataError. And it only happens during testing, not in production!  I was hoping to avoid digging into it further by getting SA to leave the secondary table alone and just trust the FKs to do their job.  Oh well, I guess I go see if I can track down the real problem.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: I think your StaleDataError may be related to the one I posted about [on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlalchemy/svoXJye2O1U/NFkKG_kzEwAJ), which was due to a stale (deleted) object being left in a relationship, and trying to delete it again in my tests. This was easy to reproduce in tests, but I first saw it in production. Unfortunately not fixed yet, you could join the thread to request a fix?